# Is the minimum marriage age for males 12 and females 9 in the Hanafi fiqh?

Tags: nikah, hanafi, children

On the [Marriageable age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriageable_age#Islam) Wikipedia page

> In Quran, the "age of marriage" coincides with puberty. Classical Islamic law (Sharia) does not have a marriageable age because there is no minimum age at which puberty can occur. However, many schools of Islamic jurisprudence (fiqh) set marriageable ages for men and women.

And lists the ages

```
          Male consent    Female consent
Hanafi         12               9
```

I'd like to fact-check these numbers and identify a reliable reference.  No inline references are given on the Wikipedia page.

**Question**: Is the minimum marriage age for males 12 and females 9 in the Hanafi fiqh?

The closest reference I found was  As-Sayyid Sabiq, *Fiqh us-Sunnah* The Book on Acts of Worship ([pdf](https://ebooks.worldofislam.info/ebooks/Hadith%20&%20Sunnah/Fiqh%20us%20Sunnah%20(Five%20Volumes).pdf)) which says:

> Fiqh 1.69: Menstruation ... Most scholars say that its time begins at the age of nine.

This seems to support part of the claim on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no minimum age for *nikah* to be valid, though it is recommended by scholars that it shouldn't be contracted before puberty. The *nikah* of a minor will be valid when contracted by their guardians at any age, though it is consummated at puberty, and the two are given a choice to annul the *nikah* at puberty if it hasn't been done by their father or grandfather.

Puberty is evident by wet dreams and menstruation. However the minimum age of puberty is 12 for boys and 9 for girls, even if the signs are evident before that. The maximum age of puberty is 18 for boys and 17 for girls (though there are other reports within the school), meaning that puberty would have passed even if there are no evident signs.

Nikah of minors in [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n287/mode/2up):

> The nikah of a minor boy or girl is permitted if they are married away
>   by the wali irrespective of the girl being a virgin or deflowered.
>
> ...
>
> He said: If they are married away by the father or the grandfather,
>   that is, the minor boy and the minor girl, they have no option, after
>   they attain puberty.
>
> ...
>
> If they are married away by someone other than the father and the
>   grandfather, then, each one of them will have the option upon
>   attaining puberty; if they like they can maintain the contract and if
>   they like they can revoke it.

Age of puberty in [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.216460/2015.216460.The-Hedaya#page/n553/mode/2up):

> The puberty of a boy is established by circumstances, or upon his
>   attaining eighteen years of age; and that of a girl by circumstances,
>   or upon her attaining seventeen years of age.
>
> ...
>
> It is to be observed that the earliest period of puberty, with respect
>   to a boy, is twelve years, and with respect to a girl, nine years.